# Getting "Database is Locked" when trying to move a list of records from one table to another table in SQLite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have a Public Sub to move a collection of records from one table to another in the same SQLite database.  First it reads a record from strFromTable, then writes it to strToTable, then deletes the record from strFromTable.  To speed things up, I've loaded the entire collection of records into a transaction.  When the list involves moving a lot of image blobs, the db gets backed up, and throws the exception "The Database is Locked".  I think what is happening is that it's not finished writing one record before it starts trying to write the next record. Since SQLite only allows one write at a time, it thows the "Locked" exception.

Here is the code that triggers the error when moving a lot of image blobs:

```
    Using SQLconnect = New SQLiteConnection(strDbConnectionString)
        SQLconnect.Open()
        Using tr = SQLconnect.BeginTransaction()
            Using SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
            
                For Each itm As ListViewItem In lvcollection
                    SQLcommand.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO {strToTable} SELECT * FROM {strFromTable} WHERE id = {itm.Tag}; DELETE FROM {strFromTable} WHERE ID = {itm.Tag};"
                    SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next

            End Using
        tr.Commit()
        End Using
    End Using
```

When I get rid of the transaction, it executes without error:

```
    Using SQLconnect = New SQLiteConnection(strDbConnectionString)
        SQLconnect.Open()
        Using SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand

            For Each itm As ListViewItem In lvcollection
                SQLcommand.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO {strToTable} SELECT * FROM {strFromTable} WHERE id = {itm.Tag}; DELETE FROM {strFromTable} WHERE ID = {itm.Tag};"
                SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next

        End Using
    End Using
```

I'm not very good with DB operations, so I'm sure there is something that needs improvement.  Is there a way to make SQLite completely finish the previous INSERT before executing the next INSERT?  How can I change my code to allow using a transaction?

Thank you for your help.

.

Comment: Is there some documentation that led you to believe that putting all the operations into one transaction would speed it up? It has to remember all the pending operations in case something goes wrong, so it seems to me that it has more work to do. Does the process appear to be limited by disk I/O? If so, giving it more work to do will slow it down.

Comment: I believe the issue you're encountering is due to transaction isolation. https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html  Your attempting to delete the same records that have been included in the initial query which is what is locked.  Transactions don't really have any notable performance gain, they a more for data security and rollback capablities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... here is the solution that I decided to go with.  I hope this helps someone finding this in a search:

```
Dim arrIds(lvcollection.Count - 1) As String
Dim i as Integer = 0

' Load the array with all the Tags in the listViewCollection
For i = 0 to lvcollection.Count - 1
    arrIds(i) = lvcollection(i).Tag 'item.Tag holds the Primary Key "id" field in the DB
Next

'build a comma-space separated string of all ids from the array of ids.
Dim strIds as String = String.Join(", ", arrIds)  

Using SQLconnect = New SQLiteConnection(strDbConnectionString)
    SQLconnect.Open()
    Using tr = SQLconnect.BeginTransaction()
        Using SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand            
            
            SQLcommand.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO {strToTable} SELECT * FROM {strFromTable} WHERE id IN ({strIds});"
            SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            SQLcommand.CommandText = $"DELETE FROM {strFromTable} WHERE ID IN ({strIds});"
            SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using
        tr.Commit()
    End Using
End Using
```

The IN statement allows me to pass all of the "id" values to be deleted as a batch.  This solution is faster and more secure than doing them one by one with no transaction.

Thanks for the comments, and best wishes to everyone in their coding.